# Omni Channel Supervisor not showing assigned queues for an agent

Tags: case, email2case, omnichannel

> We have setup Omni-Channel routing for cases in our ORG.  Everything was working fine since last week.

But today when we tested- if we add an agent to a queue

```
directly to the queue
```

### OR

`add to a public group which is assigned to queue`,

I cannot see the queue against the agent in Omni-Supervisor console tab when agent is online and neither any case is routing to the agent from that queue.

Even If I remove the agent from an existing queue/ or remove agent from public group that is part of queue, I still see the queue listed against the agent in omni-supervisor.

> I checked the user profile and they have the "Service Cloud" user license checked already - and as I said, everything was working fine a few days back.

Please advise.

Comment: Are you using omni supervisor to assign queue? Have you created service resource for that agent?

Comment: Yes, everything was working fine earlier.

Comment: was there any profile level changes recently? is the new user of the same profile?

Comment: it worked after we went offline and then online. Even refresh does not work.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the fact that one the User record you may not have "Service Cloud User" checked. You need to make sure both "Chat User" and "Service Cloud User" is checked on the User record.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out - it is some issue with Omni-Channel.
Agents have to go offline and then online to see the change.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this issue is the known issue so as a workaround, enable the omnichannel supervisor tab and get online with  the user at sfdc side, if you can see the Status of that user as available in Omnichannel supervisor tab, Select that user and go to "Change queues" and select the queue you want to assign that user, it will resolve the issue

Comment: Are there any references to be found to this "known issue"? And may I ask, what do you mean by "get online with the user at sfdc side"?

Comment: "get online with the user at sfdc side" implies that sometimes it happens that the user is online but if we check in the Omnichannel supervisor tab, it still shows the status as "Offline", contrary to this if it is being shown "Available" then it means, that user is able to take request but somehow, its assigned queue is not being shown in Omnichannel tab, even that user is  assigned in queue, so to do that, we can select that user in the "Omnichannel Supervisor tab" and select the "Change Queues" and select desired queue and save, so that the chats could be assigned to the queue.